# Can login and browse in shares on samba server, can not access files

Tags: linux, networking, samba, smb

I´m pretty new to Linux so I've been having a hard time fixing this. Running the latest version of Mint. The files are stored on an auto-mounted NTFS partition. I can access the share, I can authenticate with my owner account (the one I set a password for with `smbpasswd`) and I can browse all files and directories. However, as soon as I want to open a file it refuses.

I am using the following `smb.conf`:
http://pastebin.com/MRbgRhiG

The Videos folder is a symlink to my mounted drive, which is auto mounted as follows:

`/etc/fstab` line;

```
UUID=7C5B812C61FD7D26 /media/storage/    ntfs-3g        auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000 0 0
```

This mounts the directories for my owner account (`vincent`) and group. Same for files as proven with `ls -l` in a subdirectory under the shared folder (`Anime/Neon Genesis Evangelion/`).

```
-rwxrwxrwx 2 vincent vincent  736292972 Apr 18 00:12 Neon Genesis Evangelion 01 .mp4
```

Checking the properties of files and directories also shows full accessibility.

Comment: What does it show when it "refuses" to open?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Depends on the client used to acces, Kodi gives nothing specific and a generic error message, file browsers simply times out. Would a log be helpfull? As far as I understand smb creates logs for every client. I´ve tried to connect through a simple file browser and Kodi. Would a kodi error log be usefull?

Comment: We don't have much else to go on, so any details you can provide as to the errors would be helpful.

Comment: I would suggest you start by looking at the samba logs /var/log/samba/log.%m. This will tell you if a) the connection is even being established and if so list any errors.

Comment: @SeeJayEmm Thanks, hadn´t added those logs yet because I wasn´t sure which ones would be usefull. log.%m http://pastebin.com/1zYS29gM   If it is of any use, this is the part of the log file Kodi created when I tried to acces a file. http://pastebin.com/LaE0PYgY

Comment: @JeffSchaller This looks like your log.smbd log file. Do you have a log file for the machine that's attempting to access the samba share?

Comment: @SeeJayEmm My bad. I´m not sure whether I´ve got the right one now. The one you mean is stored on the host system right? This one was created when trying to acces a file from an Android device with a file manager. http://pastebin.com/rpzm2byP Maybe relevant; just noticed I can create folders in the shares (still gives me a timeout error on Android device, does show up on host machine though).

Comment: @Gijsbouwse I know this isn't entirely useful but the smbd process is crashing. `PANIC (pid 2596): Bad talloc magic value - access after free`. A similar condition appears to be fixed in [Samba 4.3.4](https://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-4.3.4.html).

Comment: @SeeJayEmm, I'm not the OP. Just FYI :)

Comment: @SeeJayEmm I tried looking into that after I read the logs, couldn´t find much sadly. Tried to get a clearer error response and was able to pinpoint the exact lines that are generated when a file is being accesed http://pastebin.com/Rxd0wqd5 Sadly, I´m on 4.3.8 already and the pid seems to be ¨random¨. Thanks for helping me find the logs anyways. Do you think the log linked above explains the problem and to look into fixing that/find someone who understands it? What would you suggest I do from here on?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Oops. Thanks I edited my previous response.

Comment: @Gijsbouwse The PID would be specific to the process handling that connection attempt, and it's crashing, so it would continually change. At this point you're probably looking at opening a [Samba bug report](https://bugzilla.samba.org/) or maybe with Linux Mint. A couple troubleshooting steps I'd take to try and isolate the problem.  1) Config a new share that's pointing to a directory off the root file system. This will tell you if the NTFS mount is related to the problem. 2) Check your system logs for any errors that may correspond to the samba crash `cat /var/log/syslog` and `dmesg | tail`.

Comment: @Gijsbouwse Upgrading Samba is also an option. I know you say you're on 4.3.8 but according to the logs you posted you're on 4.1.6.  `samba version 4.1.6-Ubuntu started.`

Comment: @SeeJayEmm Which is weird, considering smbd --version does actually give me 4.3.8 (proof; http://imgur.com/HNG5MCc). I´ll look into that. If I can´t find anything about it I suppose I´ll try a fresh installation. If that does not work I might submit a bug report, however I´d rather not as I´m not very familiar with Linux. If nothing fixes it I suppose it´ll end up with me staying on Windows (which I´d rather not really). Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Gijsbouwse I can't quantify it but my gut is telling me to at least eliminate the NTFS partition as a variable. Try the 2nd share before you wipe the system. If it is the NTFS partition it may just be a matter of finding the right mount or config options to make it work.

Comment: @SeeJayEmm Good call. Tried it with an unmounted directory and it gave me the same result. When I try a clean setup Iĺl make sure to get that working first before moving on to mounted stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the 4.3.8 update on Ubuntu.  There are tons of posts about it on various sites with no clear answer on a fix (as multiple people have tried various things and have had different results).

Some have found if you comment out 'security = share' (using #) in /etc/samba/smb.conf it solves the problem, however, some haven't found it to work.

Others have found adding 'client use spnego = no' to the conf has solved it, but once again others have not.

So far, I haven't found a fix that works for me and I'm on KODIbuntu 14.04.4 x86 with the 4.3.8 Samba updates.

Comment: Intresting. Thanks for the heads up. Things mentioned in your post didn´t work sadly. If it really is an Ubuntu problem I´ll be trying out a different distro. Shame, Mint seemed very beginner-friendly.